# Where to store application global settings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, architecture, coding-style

I have some global settings
For example some below are

```
ShortLeaveAllowedInOneDay = 2
LeaveAllowedInMonth = 3
```

I have following options to store these global settings

*1-Store in Database table

2-Store in Webconfig file

3-Store in class as const filed
 
4-In XML file*

Could you please suggest me which one is better approach and why

I am using Asp.net MVC3
with sqlserver 2005

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It depends** on your requirements, each one of these options has it own advantages and disadvantages.  It tried to list a few:

**1. Store in Database table** 
*Advantages:*

- Relatively easy to read settings.
- Possible to write/update settings.
- Access is to the database is fast.
- Updates to database values are immediately available.
- DB is can be shared across multiple instances in clustered environment.

*Disadvantages:*

- More infrastructure required than the rest of the options (i.e. tables, db access etc).
- If done incorrectly DB IO can become an issue. (Can be solved with caching strategies)

**2. Store in web.config file**
*Advantages:*

- Simple to add and access settings.

*Disadvantages:*

- Changes to the `web.config` may result in the application pool to restart.
- Settings are generally not encrypted.
- In a clustered environment the file has to be kept in sync with other instances.
- Generally have to deal with strings data types and possible invalid user input when settings are set.

**3. Store in class as const field** 
*Advantages:*

- Very simple to work with.
- Can work with static types.
- Good first step towards refactoring settings into one of the other options.

*Disadvantages:*

- Requires rebuild for settings to change.

**4. In XML file**
*Advantages:*

- Convenient for storing complex settings such a hierarchies.
- Custom XML config settings can be embedded inside the web.config. (Popular option see `log4net` as one such example)
- Updates to the config files can be made without restarting the application pool.
- An XSD can enforce the validity of the settings in the file (both structure and data types)

*Disadvantages:*

- It is XML.  Not *really* human readable, formats like YAML improves on that.
- Implementation required to parse XML for reading and writing settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you need them to be configured by a user of your software I would not do option 3.  If they are settings that you define as a programmer and do not expect them to be changed when your application is in production you could do that.

I would say that option 4 and 2 are basically the same, conceptually, and it is personal preference which to choose.  Personally I like to define a [custom configuration section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) and then have just that section defined in it's own .config file ([this](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2007/04/26/using-configsource-to-split-configuration-files.aspx) shows how to do that) so that you don't have a really massive web.config that the user has to navigate.

I would choose option 1 if I had a scenario where I had multiple components that all need access to the same configuration.  If all you are building is a single web application, it does not feel necessary to me to do that but if, for example, you have a web application and some other client application and both require access to the database then storing the configuration there is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Add an AppSettings session in the web config file, that can be accessed from the code directly like :

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShortLeaveAllowedInOneDay "];
```

EDIT : 
and the Confir file would look like :

```
<appSettings>

<add key="ShortLeaveAllowedInOneDay " value="2" />

</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing global variables in the web.config file is a very common task.
Storing values in your web.config file is extremely useful when a database might be overkill and when you don't need a separate external file.

Reading the .xml file several times for each page lifecycle would be VERY bad for performance.

I would definitely go for web.config.

Answer (score 0):

No approach is inherently better than the others.

The best approach depends entirely on what your requirements are for things like security, scalability, flexibility, read-only vs. writeable, config complexity, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the variable in Web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

I will be more practical. Two basic cases.

1. Values/parameters that changes ones and are critical to start/run/initialize the program
2. Values are change offend, or they are different for every user.

You store the initial variables on web.config, and all the other on database. If you do not have database, then what ever is available, like XML file.